# How to create year picker dropdown

Tags: magnolia

I wonder how to create year picker dropdown field in Magnolia.

Ideally it would list years from current year down to lets say 10 years in past.

I am new to magnolia and I can make Select field with hardcoded options but that is not great approach and I struggle how to create dynamic options. See:

```
name: year
fieldType: select
multiselect: false
label: Year
options:
  - name: 2020
    label: 2020
    selected: true
    value: 2020
  - name: 2019
    label: 2019
    selected: false
    value: 2019
```

Anyone got idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you use latest version Magnolia 6.2, you can use datasource how **Ducaz035** mentioned. See documentation here: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS62/Select+field

For previous version this way is not possible. You can only create your own field, register it and do whatever you want in the implementation. In your case, just override **getOptions** class.

```
public class YearSelectFieldFactory<D extends YearSelectFieldDefinition> extends SelectFieldFactory<D> {
    
    public YearSelectFieldFactory(D definition, Item relatedFieldItem, UiContext uiContext, I18NAuthoringSupport i18nAuthoringSupport) {
        super(definition, relatedFieldItem, uiContext, i18nAuthoringSupport);
    }

    public YearSelectFieldFactory(D definition, Item relatedFieldItem) {
        super(definition, relatedFieldItem);
    }

    @Override
    public List<SelectFieldOptionDefinition> getOptions() {
        List<SelectFieldOptionDefinition> res = new ArrayList<>();
        int currentYear = LocalDate.now().getYear();
        for (int i = currentYear - 10; i <= currentYear; i++) {
            SelectFieldOptionDefinition option = new SelectFieldOptionDefinition();
            option.setName(String.format("Year%s", i));
            option.setLabel(String.format("Year %s", i));
            option.setValue(String.valueOf(i));
            res.add(option);
        }
        res.get(0).setSelected(true);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**YearSelectFieldDefinition** just extends **SelectFieldDefinition** class. We need it to register our own field type.

To register the field add new fieldType to you module (or some other module, it doestn't matter). Here's a YAML definition for the field:

```
your-module-name:
  fieldTypes:
    yearSelectField: 
      definitionClass: com.example.fields.YearSelectFieldDefinition
      factoryClass: com.example.fields.YearSelectFieldFactory
```

Now you can use this field in your dialog definitions. Set the class for the field:

```
field:
  name: year
  class: com.example.fields.YearSelectFieldDefinition
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a datasource to the field and let the datasource provide the months for you using Java.

An example from the documentation:

```
listSelect:
  label: Contacts
  $type: listSelectField
  datasource:
    $type: jcrDatasource
    workspace: contacts
    describeByProperty: firstName
    allowedNodeTypes:
      - mgnl:contact
```

And the link to documentation directly:
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS62/Select+field